# Finder window background colour or image for USB Drive

Tags: macos, finder, customization

I would like to know how to add an image (if that's not possible then a colour) to the Finder window of my USB stick - just the stick not every window.
I have seen it on various .DMG installers (the ones which require the app to be moved into the applications folder often have an image with an arrow and a text telling the user to drag and drop) and now wonder how this is done for the window of a USB drive.

I have an application which runs straight from the stick itself without wanting to move it to the apps directory of the Mac. Every time I click on the USB drive I would like to see a custom image background (much like on those DMGs).

Search results returned old and obsolete ways or partial answers no longer supported by macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only works in icon view & as far as I'm aware only on HFS drives.
I quickly tested with a FAT32 drive which appeared to work, but didn't survive eject/insert]

- Open your folder or entire disk & set view to Icon [ <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>  ]
- Show view options [right click or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  ]
- Select Colour or Picture [for picture you then drag & drop an image to the box on the panel.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to force icon view for the drive? Would it be able to override the mac's existing settings?

Comment: It's right there on the same info panel, first line.

Comment: I see. You have been very helpful. Lastly, is there a way to have the window size fitted to the image?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware.